# Resizing images before/while base64-upload

Tags: php, mysqli, base64, image-uploading

I'm currently building some kind of chat-application, where users can upload their profile picture.
These are stored in my database and shown as base64-images.

Right now users can upload huge images, which take pretty long to be fully loaded.
Is it possible to resize these pictures to a specific size before/while they are uploaded?

Thanks! :)

Answer (score -1):

yes you can resize,invert or what you want to do can do with some third party libraries like https://github.com/claviska/SimpleImage .go thru the link.